# Is there's is any documentation for apollo client against angularjs? I have searched whole internet but all I can see is Angular2+ documentation

Tags: angularjs, apollo-client

No Documentation for apollo-client against angular 1.x

I have check official website https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/angular1-apollo

Comment: I had checked this repository as well, but I can see import statements, which is not there in AngularJS